# Android rotation issue (using canvas)

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas

I would like to draw a rectangle and insert some text.
  Then I need to rotate it by degree 90.

I create a DrawView which looks like this

```
public class DrawView extends View 
{
    public DrawView(Context context, int w, int h) 
    {  
        ...
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {  
        Point p = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point();
        ...
        super.onDraw(canvas);  

        // draw a rectangle
        canvas.drawRect(0, top, 0, top+100, p);
        canvas.drawText(str, width / 2, textBaseY, p2);
        canvas.rotate(-90.0f,...);
    }  
}
```

I have tried many times but the text doesn't rotate as I expected.
Can anyone give me some hint?
Thanks so much

Comment: move canvas.rotate two lines up

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
canvas.rotate(-90.0f, x, y);
canvas.drawRect(0, top, 0, top+100, p);
canvas.drawText(str, width / 2, textBaseY, p2);
```

If you want to restore the canvas to normal (so that it doesn't remain rotated by 90 degrees for future draws), you can do this:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(-90.0f, x, y);
canvas.drawRect(0, top, 0, top+100, p);
canvas.drawText(str, width / 2, textBaseY, p2);
canvas.restore();
```